# Visual formatting language, button width and height constraint

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, nslayoutconstraint, autolayout

Is there any way to set UIView width and height with NSLayoutConstraints?
for example i have the following constraint setup

```
subView.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false);
        let cons:NSArray =   NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("[subView(99)]", options:nil, metrics: nil, views: ["subView":subView]);
        self.view.addConstraints(cons);
```

this sets only width, how to add also a height?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Two possible options:

```
[view setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
NSArray* vConstraints = [self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[view(25)]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:view]];
[parentView addConstraints:vConstraints];
```

or

```
NSLayoutConstraint* vConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:nil attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute multiplier:1.0 constant:25];
[parentView addConstraint:vConstraint];
```

Answer (score 6):

For vertical layouts, simply add **V:** to the start of the VFL string:

```
  subView.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false);

  let horizontalCons:NSArray = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("[subView(99)]", options:nil, metrics: nil, views: ["subView":subView]);
  let veritcleCons:NSArray = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:[subView(50)]", options:nil, metrics: nil, views: ["subView":subView]);

  self.view.addConstraints(horizontalCons);
  self.view.addConstraints(veritcleCons);
```